# Odoo 14 configuration in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, odoo-14

Once I complete the configuration and hit run it's compiling correctly,

> Odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on
> DESKTOP-87PHUUM:8069

but if I open l**ocalhost:8069**  only internal server error msg is there, so I went to service and hit restart, but still, it's giving an internal server error. any ideas why I am getting this error.

Comment: write `localhost:8069/web/database/manager` in url run this

Comment: thank you adam its connecting but only the HTML form is appearing.

Comment: I can't do login or create new database . It's just HTML form.

Comment: Hey can you upload the image or logs that you are receiving whilw running the local server. It can help us out to solve your query.